# Pause timer when scroll view's slide is being touched?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to automatically scroll slides in my scroll view. I am actually doing this for my onboarding screens.
However I want the timer to pause for a while when user touches the slides and start the same again when he removes his finger.

I am doing something like this but this doesn't work for the case I am asking:

```
in viewDidLoad -
     timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 4, target: self, selector: #selector(autoScroll), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


@objc func autoScroll() {
        let totalPossibleOffset = CGFloat(topImages.count - 1) * self.view.bounds.size.width
        if offSet == totalPossibleOffset {
            //offSet = 0 // come back to the first image after the last image
            //timer.invalidate()
        }
        else {
            offSet += self.view.bounds.size.width
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveLinear, animations: {
                self.scrollView.contentOffset.x = CGFloat(self.offSet)
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(page)
        self.offSet = page * scrollView.frame.size.width // this updates offset value so that automatic scroll begins from the image you arrived at manually
    }
```

Also I have a second question: How do I start the timer interval again when user manually slides to other other. Right now, when the user slides to another slide before 4 seconds (as 4 seconds is required time to slide to another slide), say 2 seconds, he will slide to next page there after 4-2 = 2 seconds instead of 4 seconds as expected.

Comment: Where is the method that handles the user touch? And how long do you want the timer paused?

Comment: as long as it is being touched.

Comment: you should use a count variable to handle the timer callback actions. Set/reset the count variable to achieve different conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add some flag like

```
var isSlideTouched = false
```

In gesture recognizer add

```
isSlideTouched = true
```

And some code in autoScroll()

```
@objc func autoScroll() {
    if isSlideTouched {
        isSlideTouched = false
        return
    }
```